# Bind Dropdownlist with viewbag get slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to bind list into Dropdownlist using 'HtmlHelper' and it is slow. I have approximately 200K records in my dropdown list so I am using select2.js for searchable dropdown. How can I make it faster?

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StundetNumber, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StudentNumber, new { @class = "form-control StundetNumber select2", @multiple = "" })
```

Comment: What is a 'lakh'?

Comment: we can say 2 lac records.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a dropdown with 200K items in your view. You may be applying select2.js after that, but the server still has to render and serve 200K items. It's going to be slow, and the browser will have trouble rendering the intial dropdown.

You should investigate only loading the data on demand, such as select2.js provides with its AJAX support: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax